# Asterisk DID switch to out outgoing trunk?

Tags: asterisk, sip, trunk

I have a toll free DID that users call to access my PBX service on an Asterisk box. The problem is; this DID comes only with a single channel so the system can only receive one call at a time. My initial idea was to simply get the caller ID of the incoming call, disconnect the caller and issue an automated call back to him to proceed with the call. This would free up my toll free number but could be confusing for the caller of course and also, there are issues where the caller calls from behind an extension. The best solution would be to somehow seemlessly switch the call to an outgoing trunk to reconnect the caller but now using my SIP trunk.

My question is; is there a way to do this in Asterisk (or I guess, does SIP somehow allow such operation)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is called "callback".

Yes, you can do it. No, asterisk have no internal way do that and no way do it not noticable for user.